# Inequalities for generalized variance

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measured space with $\mu(X) = 1$.
Given $\phi \in L^\infty(X, \mu)$, $\phi > 0$, let me define, for $\alpha \geq 1$, $\beta > 0$, the quantity
$$
I(\alpha, \beta) = \left(\int_X \left|\phi^\beta - \mathbb{E}[\phi^\beta]\right|^\alpha d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}}.
$$

I am trying to relate the values of $I(\alpha, \beta)$ for different values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. My main concern is the following: given $\beta_0 < \beta_1 < \beta_2$, is there some sort of interpolation inequality, i.e. of the form
$$
I(\alpha, \beta_1) \leq I(\alpha, \beta_0)^\lambda I(\alpha, \beta_2)^{1-\lambda}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that was from a previous formulation of the question. I removed it.

Comment: Your "some sort of" question does not seem specific enough. I think more work should be done on this post to make it more appealing.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Indeed, thank you for your comment! My question is to know if such a quantity has appeared before and what kind of inequality has been proven about it. I have a lot of freedom in how to study my problem and properties of $I$ will dictate how I address it.